# Unable to find the column from the dataset

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw a bar graph with the `ggplot` package. However, I kept getting the following error:

> "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'deposit_type' not found"

I don't know what the issue is here. I found people who have similar questions; they were suggested to check if the column is in the data frame. I used `colnames` function and found out that `deposit_type` is not found. But when I look at the table, I can see that column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library(lubridate)
library(skimr)

# Read in the data
booking_data <- read_csv("hotel_bookings.csv")

booking_data %>% group_by(hotel) %>% summarize(total_cancellation = sum(booking_data$is_canceled)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes( x = deposit_type, y = sum(revenue) , fill= hotel )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: This is the list of columns that the dataframe has.]

Comment: Look at your data after calling `summarize()`; `deposit_type` gets dropped because it's not a grouping column or a new calculated column.

Comment: @alistaire Hi, thanks for pointing out the problem! Have a great night!

Answer (score 0):

When you summarize, you would need to specify which columns to keep. But if you just want to add another column with the sum and retain others then use `mutate`.

```
library(tidyverse)

booking_data %>% 
  group_by(hotel) %>% 
  mutate(total_cancellation = sum(is_canceled)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes( x = deposit_type, y = sum(revenue) , fill= hotel )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Whereas, with `summarise` you would need to write out the columns to keep, but these would not be summarized in any way.

```
booking_data %>% 
  group_by(hotel) %>% 
  summarize(total_cancellation = sum(is_canceled), deposit_type, revenue, hotel) %>% 
  ggplot(aes( x = deposit_type, y = sum(revenue) , fill= hotel )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! This is really helpful. Have a great night!